# Black & White time travel movie that ends with a repeating time loop

Tags: identify-this-movie, science-fiction, time-travel, black-and-white

I am looking for a black and white science fiction movie that I watched a couple of times on a Saturday or Sunday afternoon in the early to mid 1960's on local Los Angeles television.  The movie was probably made in the 1950's but it is possible it was made in the very early 60's.

The movie involved time travel or time distortion and it kept repeating the story in a loop going faster as some kind of time paradox was created.  I think it was set in the future, but I am not sure.  It ended by time just looping out of control.

I thought it was black and white, but now I realize that I really have no idea. I watched it before we got a color TV so it could have been either. Also, I now think that it was probably 1966 or 1967 that I watched the movie on TV. Does anyone have any idea what this movie was?

Comment: Are you 100% sure it was B&W and not simply watched on a B&W TV?

Comment: I thought it was black and white, but now I realize that I really have no idea.  I watched it before we got a color TV so it could have been either.

Comment: Also, I now think that it was probably 1966 or 1967 that I watched the movie on TV.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's possible you saw [The Time Travelers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Time_Travelers_%281964_film%29) (AKA Time Trap), a film about scientists travelling through time from 1964, on a B&W TV because you're pretty much describing the ending, after they manage to go back to their time:

> The survivors return to the lab, where they make a strange discovery. Their past selves are still in the lab, yet to pass through the portal, but they appear frozen. Through some error, the travelers are experiencing time at an accelerated rate; the rest of the world, including their past selves, is moving in extremely slow motion. Their only option is to travel to the date the portal had briefly been set to before being set to 2071 A.D., a date over 100,000 years in the future. But the screen is dark and what lies ahead is unknown.
>
> When the last one goes through, the screen flashes on briefly and shows the travelers walking in a clearing with trees and grass with the surface of the Earth habitable again and people able to build a future there. The film shows their past selves moving at normal speed again, repeating the actions seen at the beginning of the film. **The sequence of events of the entire movie is rapidly re-shown, and repeats faster and faster, leaving the viewer in a time loop until it abruptly ends without further explanation.**

The movie is avaliable on Youtube. Here's the trailer:

Comment: Thank you so much!  This is a movie I have wanted to re-watch for decades but I could never find it because I couldn't remember the name.  The last time I watched it I was in the first grade and didn't completely understand it but I have thought about it many times over the years.  Thank you again.